# How to create json file in hadoop file system using python

Tags: python, json, hdfs

```
 os.system('echo "%s" | hadoop fs -put -f - /app/hdp/logs/json/a.json' %(json_string))

json_string=json.dumps({"a":"b"})
```

The file got created in HDFS but with wrong json format.
The format it stored was `{a:b}` with no doubles quotes which is not a proper json format.

What is wrong in this approach?

Comment: Do you need to include some escaped `'` characters? i.e. change it to `json_string=json.dumps({"\'a\'":"\'b\'"})`

Comment: echo %s - remove the quotes

Comment: @SmartManoj it's still the same ... removing the quotes doesn't help ..

Comment: @ResetACK it is still the same ...

Comment: what happens when u manually run at terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
import subprocess, json

json_string=json.dumps({"a":"b"})

proc = subprocess.Popen('echo "{0}" | hadoop fs -put -f - /app/hdp/logs/json/a.json'.format(json_string), shell=True)
```

The string should be formatted as `"{"a":"b"}"`

Comment: I don't know what's happening in this echo to HDFS ... it is still doing {a:b} only

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess, json
json_string=json.dumps({"a":"b"})
#json_string=json_string.replace('"','\"') try escaping quotes too
proc = subprocess.run('echo {0} | hadoop fs -put -f - /app/hdp/logs/json/a.json'.format(json_string), shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include escape characters

echo "{"a":"b"}" in shell terminal

Output:
{a:b}